# What does 'table-responsive' class do in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What does that table-responsive does with the bootstrap technology. I found in w3schools about table-striped, table-bordered, and few other definitions, but nothing about the responsive

Comment: Did you even try to read to [official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)?

Comment: I did just now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the table not stretch over the width of the screen and get cut off. It keeps everything a normal size and includes a slider on the bottom to move horizontally.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive
>   to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When
>   viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any
>   difference in these tables.
>
> Vertical clipping/truncation Responsive tables make use of overflow-y:
>   hidden, which clips off any content that goes beyond the bottom or top
>   edges of the table. In particular, this can clip off dropdown menus
>   and other third-party widgets.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words 'table-responsive' wraps the table inside a div with scrollbar when there is not enough space to fit the table.